# Assume the IAM role with Boto3 script

Tags: boto3

I have put to gather a simple boto3 script that help the IAM user to generate temporarily security token session and it works fine. However, the user is still need to create three environment variables  before being able to use the assumed role, I have tried to add this step also to the script so I can make the process fully automated, but for some reasons its not working.

The script that only generate the credentials and print them out for the user is as follow:

```
import boto3
import argparse
import os
import subprocess

class AssumeRole(object):
  def __init__(self,role,accesskey,secretkey):
    session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=accesskey,
    aws_secret_access_key=secretkey,)
    sts_client = session.client('sts')
    response = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=role,RoleSessionName="filler1",)
    self.AK =  (response['Credentials']["AccessKeyId"])
    self.SK =  (response['Credentials']["SecretAccessKey"]) 
    self.ST = (response['Credentials']["SessionToken"])
    print (f"The access key is: ", self.AK)
    print (f"The secret key is: ", self.SK)
    print (f"The token key is: ", self.ST)
    return None

def parse_args():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ARN of role')
  parser.add_argument('--role', required=True)
  parser.add_argument('--accesskey', required=True)
  parser.add_argument('--secretkey', required=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  return args

def main():
  args = parse_args()
  Per1 = AssumeRole(args.role,args.accesskey,args.secretkey)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Now, the part I have added to the script in order to create the enviroment variable is as follow:

```
import boto3
import argparse
import os
import subprocess

class AssumeRole(object):
  def __init__(self,role,accesskey,secretkey):
    session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=accesskey,
    aws_secret_access_key=secretkey,)
    sts_client = session.client('sts')
    response = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=role,RoleSessionName="filler1",)
    self.AK =  (response['Credentials']["AccessKeyId"])
    self.SK =  (response['Credentials']["SecretAccessKey"]) 
    self.ST = (response['Credentials']["SessionToken"])
    self.export()
    return None

  def export(self):

    cmd = ["set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID =  " + self.AK + "  ", "set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= =  " + self.SK + "  ", "set AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=None  " + self.ST + "  "]
    for each in cmd:
      os.system(each)
    os.system('aws sts get-caller-identity')
    return None

def parse_args():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ARN of role')
  parser.add_argument('--role', required=True)
  parser.add_argument('--accesskey', required=True)
  parser.add_argument('--secretkey', required=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  return args

def main():
  args = parse_args()
  Per1 = AssumeRole(args.role,args.accesskey,args.secretkey)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The commands that I have added in the second method **def export()** works perfectly if I put it directly on to CLI , but here in the code is not working?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: That's because it sets the variable in a shell and then the shell exits. You can't modify environment variables of another process.

Comment: Perhaps your script should just write out `~/.aws/credentials`? Otherwise, I don't see anything this script does that `aws sts assume-role` cli does not